# What is the beeja mantra for kuber?

Tags: mantras, kubera

I am looking for the beeja mantra for kuber with reference. 
Are there any combined lakshi kuber mantra also. Please help Thanks

Comment: https://www.drikpanchang.com/vedic-mantra/gods/shri-kubera/kubera-mantras.html

Answer (score 2):

I do not know Kuber beejmantra.
But I know the mantra of Devi Lakshmi which made Kuber rich, Ravna able to build his golden Lanka.

The mantra is described in Devi Bhagvat.

Mantra is,

> Om Srim Hrim Klim Aem Kamalvasinyaiye Swaha
>
> ओम श्रीं ह्रीं क्लीं ऐं कमलवासिन्यै स्वाहा |

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The beej mantra for Kuber is 'Dhaam', if you still don't know. Here's a link of someone chanting it 1008 times, https://youtu.be/y8UWDA-_6sQ. You can learm the correct pronunciation from that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).